# CSS: content border crosses fixed footer border

Tags: html, css, fixed

I have a fixed footer div and a content div. Content div is 100% height and I want it not to go through the footer, although I do not want to give percent value that is less than 100%.

```
<!-- fixed --><div id="footer" style="border:4px solid black;">
<div>

<!-- crosses the footer thus fails --><div id="content" style="border:4px solid blue;">
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TAVmF/2/

Bottom border of blue box should be on top of black box's border AND it should not cross it.

A result of the way I want it to be is next: http://i49.tinypic.com/2hs3mna.jpg

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position:fixed` from footer and interchange the html code of `container` and `footer` divs.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TAVmF/3/)**

---

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/TAVmF/5/)**

Comment: no, I need footer to be fixed, being visible at any point of scroll

Comment: yes, it's working, you've done great job. thank you very much.

Comment: You realize because of the order of your CSS you're overwriting the position fixed on the footer anyway right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set content `max-height` at run time using `jquery` and add `overflow:auto` in content style.

Suppose your `content max-height = screenheight - footer height.`

Hope this formula help you.